# How do I loop Through Each Records in SQL server with Time Gap

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am making a CMS portal for my company which will fetch records from SQL server using ASP.NET:

My problem is that when I fetch values it only shows the last one. But my need is that it should display one by one values with say 5-10 seconds gap in between here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=soemserv;Initial Catalog=data;User Id=master; Password=hushotn;"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        conn.Open()
        Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select Queue,[Timing(IST)],[Status at],TAT,[Staffing at] from DTD_LCD_Queue_Status", conn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read()
            lblQueueName.Text = reader("Queue").ToString.Trim
            lblTimingIST.Text = reader("Timing(IST)").ToString.Trim
            lblStatusAt.Text = reader("Status at").ToString.Trim
            lblTAT.Text = reader("TAT").ToString.Trim
            lblStaffingAt.Text = reader("Staffing at").ToString.Trim
        End While


    End Sub

End Class
```

How do I loop though each record I tried `Do` and `Loop` but its not working...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
**One Step Ahead with no LUCK!!!!**
I have written this code but still getting the last row only

```
For I As Integer = 0 To 15

            lblTemp.Text = I.ToString
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select Queue,[Timing(IST)],[Status at],TAT,[Staffing at] from DTD_LCD_Queue_Status where SrNo='" + lblTemp.Text + "';", conn)

            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader

            While reader.Read()


                lblQueueName.Text = reader("Queue").ToString.Trim
                lblTimingIST.Text = reader("Timing(IST)").ToString.Trim
                lblStatusAt.Text = reader("Status at").ToString.Trim
                lblTAT.Text = reader("TAT").ToString.Trim
                lblStaffingAt.Text = reader("Staffing at").ToString.Trim
                Thread.Sleep(2000)
            End While

        Next
```

**Note** I have dynamically given rows i.e 0 to 15

Please guide me!!

Comment: I'm a VB.NET windows forms developer, not so much an ASP.NET developer, so I may be completely wrong here; but can you use timers in ASP.NET?  I tried once and failed to get it to work.  Were this a windows forms application I'd say just have a timer that fires your code above on its interval event and increments through each record.

Comment: It is a webform..so i don't know how to trigger a Timer event on this..

Comment: I'd loop through the sqldatareader and stick the data in a javascript array - and then use setInterval to display the elements in the array every 5 seconds.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse...you will please guide me doing the above, I twould be of great help

Comment: @user3766876 - sorry haven't got time at the moment to find some code ... if I get a chance this evening I'll find something and post it.

Comment: You can either dump all the records in a javascript array and use `setInterval` to pull and display one record at a time at timed interval. The other way could be to use asp.net `UpdatePanel` along with `Timer` to show one record at a time at timed interval.

Answer (score 0):

- **Only the last values are printed** because : you are fetching a group of rows(data) through the `readr` and in first *iteration* of the `while loop` the first rows(data) are copied to the controls then for the second iteration the contents in the controls are **over written with the second row**. This will happens in each iteration hence only the **last data are displayed**.

  **- This can be avoided by using**
- Group of controls which are dynamically created(but not practical and good)
- using DataGridView(grid) to display the items [How to do this](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_binding.htm)

**The method you ware suggested (using Timer) is also possible but it is not a good programming practice only the last values ware displayed all the others flashed for a duration of 5-10 seconds **